# access environment variables in Python inside many files

Tags: python, flask, dotenv

if i need to get the value of an environment variables inside many files in the project Python (flask framework) should i use os.environ['HOME'] for every use or there is better way?

for example:
auth\routes.py

```
username= os.environ.get("USERNAME")
```

and in routes under posts
posts\routes.py

```
username= os.environ.get("USERNAME")
```

Comment: Specifically for a Flask app, you should read env variables *once* and put them as config on the Flask app, then access it from there. Whether you use `get` or `[]` just depends on whether you *require* the variable to exist or accept `None` for undefined variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a common file to read all your environmental values.

**config.py**

```
import os

USERNAME = os.environ.get("USERNAME")
```

Then you can reuse it like this,

**auth\routes.py**

```
import config

username = config.USERNAME
```